# Windows Phone - Does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, datasnap

I'm developing an app for windows phone, based on DataSnap (Delphi).

However, the error is displayed for reference `System.Windows.Threading;` :

The type or namespace name 'Threading' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I add `WindowsBase.dll`, but not resolved.

Comment: What class are you trying to use?

Comment: The `DSRESTConnection` class, automatic generated from the DataSnap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all libraries that are usually available in a .Net environment are available in WP environment.

Use aync and await for implementing threading. 
Check this intro to async and await : [Asynchronous Programming For Windows Phone 8](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8)